# z3 tactics are not available via online interface

Tags: z3

I print the list of tactics in Z3.

```
for (int i=0;i < Z3_get_num_tactics(z3_cont);i++)
    cout<<"\n"<<Z3_get_tactic_name(z3_cont,i);
```

1. qflra
2. qfnia
3. qfbv
4. qfnra
5. qflia
6. recover-01
7. factor
8. add-bounds
9. propagate-ineqs
10. diff-neq
11. degree-shift
12. lia2pb
13. fm
14. pb2bv
15. normalize-bounds
16. purify-arith
17. nla2bv
18. fix-dl-var
19. distribute-forall
20. elim-term-ite
21. simplify
22. elim-and
23. ctx-simplify
24. snf
25. nnf
26. der
27. cofactor-term-ite
28. elim-uncnstr
29. split-clause
30. symmetry-reduce
31. occf
32. tseitin-cnf
33. tseitin-cnf-core
34. solve-eqs
35. propagate-values
36. reduce-args
37. skip
38. fail
39. fail-if-undecided
40. bv1-blast
41. bit-blast
42. max-bv-sharing
43. reduce-bv-size
44. qfnra-nlsat
45. nlsat
46. sat
47. sat-preprocess
48. smt
49. ctx-solver-simplify
50. aig
51. horn
52. unit-subsume-simplify
53. qe-light
54. qe-sat
55. qe
56. vsubst
57. quasi-macros
58. bv
59. ufbv
60. macro-finder
61. fpa2bv
62. qffpa
63. qffpabv
64. qfbv-sls
65. subpaving

Also, I find that not all of them I could use via online interface. The question is: where can I find documentation (maybe some papers) about them? And which are available in online interface?

Answer (score 1):

There is a thorough online tutorial on using tactics on http://rise4fun.com/z3py. 
It contains pointers to papers, including:
Leonardo de Moura and Grant Passmore. The Strategy Challenge in SMT Solving, volume 7788 of  Lecture Notes in Artificial Intelligence. Springer, 2013. It explains the use of basic combinators (fail, skip, and-then, etc).
It is accessible from 
 http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/publications/index.html

To get the most detailed information about each tactic, 
there is the Z3 source code publicly available from http://z3.codeplex.com.

Comment: Thank you for the links! But I haven't found information about which tactics are available in online interface.