# z3py expression simplification

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to simplify an expression using z3py but am unable to find any documentation on what different tactics do. The best resource I have found is a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167088/z3-tactics-are-not-available-via-online-interface) that lists all the tactics by name.

Is someone able to link me to detailed documentation on the tactics available?
The on line python tutorials are not sufficient.

Or can someone recommend a better way to accomplish this.

An example of the problems is an expression such as:

`x < 5, x < 4, x < 3, x = 1` I would like this to simplify down to `x = 1`.

Using the tactic `unit-subsume-simplify` appears works for this example.

But when I try a more complicated example such as `x > 1, x < 5, x != 3, x != 4` I get `x > 1, x < 5, x ≠ 3, x ≠ 4` as the result. When I would like `x = 2`.

What is the best approach to achieve this type of simplification using z3py?

[My current solution](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/QLRG).

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x < 5, x < 4, x < 3, x == 1)
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
s1 = Solver()
s1.add(x > 1, x < 5, x != 3, x != 4)
print s1.check()
m1 = s1.model()
print m1
```

Output:

```
sat
[x = 1]
sat
[x = 2]
```

Run this solution online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/0slb)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not looking the solvers solution. I want to remove weaker terms and simplify the expression. 

For the input:

`x < 5, x < 4, x < 3`

I want the result:

`x < 3`

Comment: I am not an expert but I think that for your problem is more better to use the package Redlog of Reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Example with Redlog of Reduce.  Please let me know what do you think.

[image]